# Rails ActiveSupport::Concern and method evaluation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, activesupport-concern

I have this application which uses Devise with `current_user` helper. When I create a module, `current_user` becomes `nil` after I mention an attribution to it even though it never happens.

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  include ModuleTest

  def index
    a_test_method
  end
end
```

And the **ModuleTest**:

```
module ModuleTest
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def a_test_method
    puts "(BEFORE)===========> #{current_user.inspect}"
    current_user = nil if false
    puts "(AFTER) ===========> #{current_user.inspect}"
  end
 end
```

Output:

```
(BEFORE)===========> #<User id: 1>
(AFTER) ===========> nil
```

**However**, if I delete/comment out this line `# current_user = nil if false`, `current_user` remains valid:

```
(BEFORE)===========> #<User id: 1>
(AFTER) ===========> #<User id: 1>
```

Would this be related to lazy evaluation somewhat?

**EDIT**

The whole problem relies on how Ruby defines variables when a statement is not evaluated:

```
2.3.4 (main):0 > defined? this_never_seen_variable_before
=> nil
2.3.4 (main):0 > this_never_seen_variable_before = "value" if false
=> nil
2.3.4 (main):0 > defined? this_never_seen_variable_before
=> "local-variable"
2.3.4 (main):0 >
2.3.4 (main):0 > this_never_seen_variable_before_2
   NameError: undefined local variable or method `this_never_seen_variable_before_2' for main:Object
from (pry):119:in `<main>'
2.3.4 (main):0 > this_never_seen_variable_before_2 = "value" if false
=> nil
2.3.4 (main):0 > this_never_seen_variable_before_2
=> nil
2.3.4 (main):0 >
```

How does this work underneath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `current_user` is a helper **method** provided by Devise, not a local variable.
2. There is no such helper method named `current_user=`. You can prove this by changing `current_user = nil` to `self.current_user = nil` and see it crash. But this is irrelevant to your issue.

So the result is, you defined a local variable `current_user` between the 2 `puts`, which shadows the helper method with the same name.

The weird thing is, although `current_user = nil` is not executed because of the `if false`, the local variable still gets defined, and its value is implicitly set to `nil`. This is why your second `puts` shows `nil`. Even if you change your `current_user = nil` to `current_user = :someone`, your second `puts` should still show `nil`.